# Is it a good practice to use PHP on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: php

Now I'm trying to develop an IoT project basd on [RPi 3B](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b/) which will have user interface based on thin client technology. So PHP looks attractive to be used in this application.

I know that PHP has many disadvantages but it is still widely used for web developing.

I would definitely consider PHP as a core technology for web development but is there anything should be taken into account on RPi platform?

Comment: Raspbian is a Linux distribution. Anything you might use on any Linux system is OK.

Comment: @RomanMatveev The Pi is a standard Linux box.

Comment: Welcome.  In case it isn't clear, it's no better or worse than using PHP anywhere else.  There are always nuanced opinions about the use of any programming language, but this is not really an appropriate place to express and discuss them.

Comment: @goldilocks I'm agree that it is nuanced anyway. But some technologies are bad on some hardware platforms: Linux can run on STM32 but it can be a bad practice, Windows can run on Pi, but it is not a good idea as well. So please consider to keep the question :)

Comment: *"Windows can run on Pi, but it is not a good idea as well"* is a good analogy, because that would also be considered opinion based here. Obviously, some people do it, no doubt some of them are very technically proficient, and at least some of those are going to say it's no worse to run Windows on a Pi than anything else. Etc. The point is, if you have a *concrete and objective* question about using Windows or PHP on the Pi, where the brand of hardware is relevant in some sense, great.  But while you might get any number of concrete and objective *answers*, that does not mean this question is.

Comment: For example: *"Can I run application foo on Windows on a Pi?"* is an objective question, to which there is an objective answer, an answer which might also show up as an answer to the mostly opinion based subjective question, *"Is it a good idea to run Windows on a Pi?"*: "No, because you cannot use application foo, and of course everyone knows Windows is pointless without foo" <- also notice how that is now infected by the subjective nature of the discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Pi is a standard Linux box it will run all the standard tools.

The Pi's limitations are its relatively weak processors and its relatively limited RAM.

Comment: I know that I CAN run PHP on Pi. But the question was about exactly what you've stated in your answer: the Pi hardware limitations. So I feel free to use PHP but will check the resources carefuly.